# How to auto restart rails server with grunt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gruntjs

I am working with rails-api so each time i change controller or Route file i want to auto reload rails server, so new changes will be applied.

I got basic setup to work with this plugin: [link](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-rails-server), where rails start together with grunt.

The problem is i want to reload rails server each time any rails files are changed.

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: You do not need to restart Rails app in development when controller is changed. Only when anything in `config/` change.

Comment: Look at the ans, it my help you more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193387/restart-rails-server-automatically-after-every-change-in-controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. You will need to use **[Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard)** for this purpose. Please read carefully [Guards official page](https://github.com/guard/guard). They're doing good job in explaining how to setup your development environment.

There are tutorials on [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard) and also on [NetTuts](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/guard-is-your-best-friend--net-31021).

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that there is second(but definitely not the last one) option to achieve this. If you start using **[Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring)** which is Rails application preloader. Read more about this on [Github page](https://github.com/rails/spring).

Here is great tutorial on how to setup everything together - http://girders.org/blog/2014/02/06/setup-rails-41-spring-rspec-and-guard/